# Lambda moment utc time set hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, momentjs

When i run the following in a AWS lambda hosted in us-east-1

```
const currentTime = moment().utc().valueOf();
console.log(new Date( currentTime ));//1538003255995
Prints: Wed Sep 26 2018 19:07:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) --- Correct in terms of current time.

const currentExecution = moment().set({
  hour: 19,
  minute: 24,
  second: 0
}).utc().valueOf();
console.log(new Date( currentTime ));//1537989840995
Prints:Wed Sep 26 2018 15:24:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Why is it showing 15:24 instead of 19:24?
But when i run this code in my local machine located in EST it prints
`Wed Sep 26 2018 19:24:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

Why is there a 4 hr difference when run in lambda alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `new Date` takes the local timestamp, so it returns *the time at the place where you were when it was 19:07 at UTC, which is 15:07*. Thats different with AWS as they probably use no timezone offset, so the server behaves as if it was in UTC

You might want to use `Date.UTC` ... [goto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: So @JonasWilms how to tell lambda to behave in specified timezone ?